# How to use browse for dll action in advanced UI project?

Tags: installshield

- Using advanced user interface project for packing my wix msi with
            installer.I hope this project type is suitable for me . Now want to validate key via registration page (Customized dialog),so how can we do this action in install shield ?
  I found one option in button
            control Events and its has option browse for dll action but its not
            working for me.I have a C# windows installer CA library for key
            validation but its not working in this action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if i got you but this is how i call c# CA in suite.

1. add this .dll into a support files
2. then go to Events tab, right click Actions and pick Managed code
   [image]
3. with button down, i pick the file from step 1), define Class and Method of the .dll
4. do something with this event in wizard or if u want you can schedule it in the events on bottom part of the Events view

If you did this way, maybe try to add some message box into the .dll? or look into a log setup.exe "Setup.exe" /debuglog"c:\path\to.log" and see if theres some error

Comment: then go to Events tab, right click Actions and pick Managed code please share the screen shot for this option

Comment: I added the image for the second step, i'm using Installshield 2015